# Удаление из базы значений через checkbox и inpute

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, есть скрипт вывода таблицы из базы, как сделать удаление определенной строки при нажатии на inpute

```
<?php 
    $qr_result = mysql_query("select * from " . x_comment) or die(mysql_error());

    // выводим на страницу сайта заголовки HTML-таблицы
    echo '<table class="table_admin_ot">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th><input type="checkbox" id="cheackbox_otziv_all" name="id" /></th>';
    echo '<th>Девочка</th>';
    echo '<th>Имя</th>';
    echo '<th>E-Mail</th>';
    echo '<th>Комментарий</th>';
    echo '<th>Дата</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';

   // выводим в HTML-таблицу все данные клиентов из таблицы MySQL 
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
printf("
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='cheackbox_otziv' name='id' value='%s'/></td>
<td><a href=girl.php?id='%s'>555</a></td>
<td>%s</td>
<td>%s</td>
<td>%s</td>"
, $data['id'], $data['id_profile'], $data['name'], $data['email'], $data['comment']);

    }

    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';

echo "<input type='submit' value='Удалить' name='sub_del'/>";

?>
```

Заранее всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы срабатывало удаление по отмеченным чекБоксам есть 2 варианта:

1. Нужно сделать тег формы, чтобы собрать все чекБоксы в одну форму:

   `<form action="ссылка на скрипт который будет обрабатывать удаление" name="table" method="POST (ну или GET - разницы особой нет)">
    <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>ID<th/>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="all" /><th/>
            <th>Name<th/>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php foreach($mnogo as $odin): ?>
        <tr>
           <td><?=$odin['id']?></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?=$odin['id']?>" /></td>
           <td><?=$odin['name']?></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Удалить" />
   </form>`

Обратите внимание что чекБоксы у каждой строки имеют имя `check[]`. Квадратные скобки в итоге дадут возможность накапливать выбранные значения и на странице обработки вы получите список:

`var_dump($_POST['check']);` выведет
`array(1,3,7,9)` конечно в том случае если были выбраны чекБоксы с ID 1,3,7,9.

Если сделать имя без квадратных скобок, то значение будет переписываться, и оно будет одно.

`var_dump($_POST['check']);` выведет `9` при таком же раскладе выбранных чекБоксов.

2 Вариант - можно сделать через AJAX запрос.

Так же добавляем форму вначале таблицы, чтобы удобнее было обрабатывать
Так же выводим форму
Подключаем jQuery
и в скрипте JavaScript прописываем.

```
 var selected = [];
    $('form[name=table] input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        var checkbox_value = $(this).val();
        selected.push(checkbox_value);
    });
    $.ajax({
    url : 'ссылка на скрипт который обрабатывает запрос',
    type : 'POST',
    data : { check: selected },
    success : function(response) {
        if(response === "ok") {
            $('form[name=table] input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                 $(this).parent().parent().fadeIn('fast');
            });
        }
    }
    });
```

В скрипте обработчике получаем опять массив на удаление `$_POST['check']`, удаляем в цикле и по оконцове делаем  `exit('ok');`
Это ОК получит скрипт `$.ajax();` и удалит ячейки из таблицы с выбранными чекбоксами.

Comment: А как собственно сам обработчик сделать не подскажите?

Comment: Ну вот у тебя приходят POST данные в массиве $_POST['check'] в нем хранятся числа, которые Вы выбрали в таблице. Делаем  foreach($_POST['check'] as $id) {  $query = "DELETE FROM `таблица` WHERE id = " . (int) $id;  mysql_query($query);  }  если уж на то пошло.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вот еще одна помощь нужна ( как сделать две кнопки одну на удаление, а вторую на замену значения строки act_comm в структуре таблицы x_comment

Comment: Не совсем понятен 2 Вариант, можно по подробнее расписать, как отправить с формы на  JavaScript, а потом на обработчик????
 

Answer (score 0):

отправляете get или post запрос на сервер указав id записи (вы его знаете $data['id']), и выполняете уже на сервере удаление, в случае успеха перезагружаете страницу и все.
есть куча скособов как это сделать.
Что у вас не получилось?

Comment: мои знания слабы, как реализовать, при выборе чекбокса и нажатии на инпут удаления удалялась запись в базе? с определенным айди

Answer (score 0):

[depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

```
Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
функции:
```

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)